# Comparing edit control value with mysql database value

Tags: mysql, winapi, visual-c++

Hello i want to execute a `mysql` query in `vc++` with where clause

```
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    stmt = con->createStatement();
      res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * from MEMBERS");
```

now i want to add WHERE clause in query.But problem is the value with which i want to compare is coming from edit control and stored into `wchar_t`.Is it possible to pass wchar_t value in where and in last i want to check if return value have row or not??

Comment: Use WideCharToMultiByte to convert wchar_t to char. And then append it to the query. Alternatively if you want only to use ANSI version of the api, undefine UTF8 in your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after some try i finally found the answer

```
pstmt = con->prepareStatement("select * from users where user_name =? and user_password=?");
  pstmt->setString(1,user);
  pstmt->setString(2,pass);
```

and for conversion of wchar_t i used

```
wcstombs
```